# Minimal orders of symmetric groups whose subgroup is isomorphic to a sporadic group

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is well known that every group is isomorphic with a subgroup of some symmetric group.
So I am interested with the case of the sporadic groups and I am asking if for each of them the minimal order of a symmetric group having a subgroup isomorphic with this sporadic group is known.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to asking for the minimal degree of a faithful permutation representation of each sporadic simple group. Such a representation is transitive and primitive.I presume these are by now tabulated, but I do not know a reference.

Comment: You can find all of this information in the ATLAS of Finite Groups. In fact all of the maximal subgroups of all of the sporadic  groups are known except for a very small number of uncertainties about whether certain groups arise as maximal subgroups of the Monster. But they all involve possible subgroups of very large index.

Comment: Just to spell out the details implicit in the previous comments: An embedding $G \subset S_n$ is the same as a degree-$n$ permutation representation (i.e. an action of $G$ on a set of order $n$), and minimality implies it is transitive and so this is the action of $G$ on $G/H$ for some subgroup $H \subset G$ (namely, the stabilizer of a point), and so you are asking for the subgroup of $G$ of maximal order (hence minimal $n = |G/H|$). The maximal-order subgroups of sporadic groups are known, and available for example in the ATLAS.

Comment: For example, if $M_n$ is a sporadic [Mathieu group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group) (i.e. $n=11,12,22,23,24$), then $n$ is the minimal number $m$ such that $M_n \subset S_m$, because $M_{n-1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $M_n$ of maximal order, and $|M_n : M_{n-1}|=n$. Note that $M_{n-1}$ is not sporadic when $n=11,22$.

Comment: Thank you very much for thesevinformations and explanations

Comment: To clarify one detail in the comment of Theo Johnson-Freyd and connect with the comment of Geoff Robinson: one also wants the permutation representation to be faithful, which corresponds to the subgroup $H$ being core-free.  Of course, this is trivial in a simple group.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd To spell out all details, you may want to explain why minimality implies transitivity, as this is not true for all groups.

Comment: @verret I don't understand your comment. If $G$ is not transitive, then the map $G \to S_n$ factors through $S_m$ for $m<n$. Ah, maybe you are worried that that map is not an injection.

Comment: $C_6$ embeds transitively only in $S_6$, but it embeds intransitively in $S_5$.

Comment: Basically, we are looking for a set of subgroups $H_1,\ldots,H_k$ (one point-stabiliser for each orbit) such that the intersection of all the cores is trivial, and we want to minimise the sum of the indices $|G:H_i|$.

Since $G$ is simple, we can take $k=1$ and take a largest maximal subgroups, but often the minimal embedding is not transitive.

Comment: You are asking for a table of $P(T)$ values for sporadic $T$. For non-sporadic simple groups $T$ a good reference is Table 4 of a 2015 paper by Guest-Morris-Praeger-Spiga. Warning: there is a typo for the value of $P(E_7)$, the factor $q^5-1$ should be $q^5+1$ (see Vassilev original paper).